# How can I refer to the values in the list?

Tags: c#, xamarin

How can I refer to the values in the list on SearchResponseModel => SearchResultModel  ?

```
    public class SearchResponseModel
    {
        public class SearchResultModel
        {
            [JsonProperty("uin")]
            public Int64 Uin { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("login")]
            public string Login { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("registration_number")]
            public List<string> RegistrationNumberList { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("type_search")]
            public int TypeSearch { get; set; }
        }
.....
        [JsonProperty("search_result")]
        public List<SearchResultModel> SearchResult { get; set; }
    }
```

In SearchModel I need get Uin and Login

```
public class SearchModel
    {
        public SearchModel(SearchResponseModel model)
        {
            Uin = model.SearchResult. ???????
        }

        public Int64 Uin { get; set; }

        public string Login { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Well which `Uin` do you want it to be? There could be 0, 1 or multiple models in the results.

Comment: In public async Task<List<SearchResultModel>> Search(SearchRequestModel model) I get Uin. And this Uin want get in my SearchModel

Comment: @Monaco that point is that you don't get Uin. You get List<SearchResultModel>, which means you get _some_amount_of_ Uins. Mayby zero. Maybe one. Maybe two hundreds.

Comment: @JonSkeet Can I use  var result = SearchItems.Select(x => new SearchModel(x)).ToList(); in ViewModel 

SearchItems is from  return from Task<List<SearchResultModel>> Search(SearchRequestModel model)

Comment: No, fundamentally the problem is that your `SearchResponseModel` could contain 0, 1 or multiple `SearchResultModel` values, whereas your `SearchModel` appear to only be interested in a single result. You need to work out what you actually want here, and we can't help you with that.

Comment: I wont transfer Uin and Login in my method
    private async void OnSearchItem()
        {
            var result = SearchItems.Select(x => new SearchModel(x)).ToList();
            NavigateBackPopup();

            await NavigateToPage(new UserProfilePage(uin, login.); 
        }

Comment: @JonSkeet when i select item in my list the uin is transfer to new page

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what you mean by that, but fundamentally your `SearchModel` appears to represent a *single* `SearchResultModel`, whereas you currently have *multiple* `SearchResultModels` for each `SearchResponseModel` - so it doesn't make sense to have a `SearchModel(SearchResponseModel)` constructor.